# Background is not showing

Tags: html, css

my background is not working. I don't know why. I dont know if i have to enter my full path (for example: C:/Users/User etc.) Maybe you can help me :O

Here is my code:

```
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.body {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    background-color: #878787;
}

.main {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `bg.jpg` image relative to this CSS file (or HTML, if this is just embedded CSS)

Comment: Could you provide a piece of HTML? I'm pretty sure that the path is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body is a html element and not a class.

So delete the . before the body.

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    ...
}
```

Comment: OHHHH, yeah right. That was the error. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Perfect I am pleased xD When this solves your problem you can accept the answer when you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

share directory structure so that we could know better.

if the css file and `bg.jpg` are in same folder then you could try

```
background-image:url("./bg.jpg");
```